# How to get Row Number List Group

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my current table result after select

```
select waktuabsen::date as Date, waktuabsen as AttendanceTime 
from tabsen
```

[image]

I want to add a column that counts the group list no. Let's just the column `GroupListNo` and the result that I want should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want `dense_rank()`:

```
select waktuabsen::date as Date, waktuabsen as AttendanceTime,
       dense_rank() over (order by waktuabsen::date) as grouplistno
from tabsen t;
```